# How to make PolyLine in leaflet having end edges rounded

Tags: leaflet

I am drawing a polyline in my leaflet map. I am keeping the stroke width high for my purpose. But with this large stroke width i see that the polyline is rounded at the corners. But i don't want the round edges. The image below shows the round corners. How can i make the edges rectangular so that the line looks like a rectangle.

[image]

Here is the code i am using for generating the polyline.

```
 var pointA = new L.LatLng(lat1, lon1);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(lat2, lon2);
    var pointList = [pointA, pointB];
    var brokenroad = new L.Polyline(pointList {
    color: 'red',
    weight: 40,
    opacity: 0.5,
    smoothFactor: 1
    });
    map.addLayer(firstpolyline);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer and its working. My updated code is

```
 var pointA = new L.LatLng(lat1, lon1);
var pointB = new L.LatLng(lat2, lon2);
var pointList = [pointA, pointB];
var brokenroad = new L.Polyline(pointList {
color: 'red',
weight: 40,
opacity: 0.5,
lineCap: "square",
smoothFactor: 1
});
map.addLayer(firstpolyline);
```